# Visifire inquiry

Tags: silverlight, visifire

I created a pie chart using visifire in silverlight.
Is there a way to customize the size of the pie itself?

Here is my code:

```
                    <visifire:Chart.Titles>
                        <visifire:Title FontSize="12" Text="{Binding GraphName}" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
                    </visifire:Chart.Titles>

                    <visifire:Chart.Series>

                        <visifire:DataSeries RenderAs="Pie" LabelEnabled="false" Bevel="True" ShadowEnabled="true" Cursor="Hand" YValueFormatString="'$'######.## "
                        LightingEnabled="False" BorderColor="DarkBlue" 
                        BorderThickness=".24" ShowInLegend="True" IncludePercentageInLegend="True" DataSource="{Binding PersonPositionGraphList}">

                            <visifire:DataSeries.DataMappings>
                                <visifire:DataMapping MemberName="AxisXLabel" Path="PositionName"/>
                                <visifire:DataMapping MemberName="YValue" Path="PositionCount"/>
                            </visifire:DataSeries.DataMappings>

                        </visifire:DataSeries>
                    </visifire:Chart.Series>
                </visifire:Chart>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is no separate property available to control the size of the Pie. You need to increase the chart size or reduce the font size of the pie labels by setting LabelFontSize property in DataSeries. If Pie displays long labels then you can break the labels into multiple lines by adding '\n'.

Also you can try setting DockInsidePlotArea="True" in custom Legend. If legend is inside the PlotArea then PlotArea size will increase and pie size will also increase accordingly. Then you can maintain the position and size of the legend by setting HorizontalAlignment, VerticalAlignment, MaxWidth/MaxHeight properties in Legend in order to avoid overlap.